# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn' has no attribute 'TensorFlowDNNClassifier'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow

**This is the ml tensorflow code I am trying to execute** -

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics
iris = datasets.load_iris()
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, classifier.predict(iris.data))

print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

**It gives the following error** -

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\admin\test3.py", line 5, in
>
> classifier = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3) AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn'
>   has no attribute 'TensorFlowDNNClassifier'
>
> [Finished in 69.3s with exit code 1]
>
> [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\admin\test3.py"]

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to have been a major refactor in the TensorFlow project, and all the `skflow` code has been moved under the main [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) repository.

Try to replace `TensorFlowDNNClassifier` with just `DNNClassifier`. The new class can be found out [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/584d4921014db921a8f4722749adff09737826a8/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py#L183). Your corrected code will look like,

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics
iris = datasets.load_iris()
# made a change in the next line
classifier = skflow.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, classifier.predict(iris.data))

print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Comment: thanks it worked !!! also the problem was with the version of tensorflow since the syntax I used has become obsolete,even reverting back to prior version solved the problem

Comment: how to revert back to previous version ??

Answer (score -1):

```py
import tensorflow.contrib.learn.python

from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python import learn as learn
```

Comment: contrib is not available in tensorflow2