# Tensorflow-example with flowers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried out this most basic example with the very nice flowers. According to this older question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380178/6444605) there have been some changes. But is this example up-to-date now too? I ask, because I get this error:

> classifier = skflow.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
>   n_classes=3) TypeError: _ _ init _ _() takes at least 3 arguments (3
>   given)

That's the code:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics
iris = datasets.load_iris()
# made a change in the next line
classifier = skflow.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, classifier.predict(iris.data))

print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to tell where the features are:

```
classifier = skflow.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=..., hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3)
```

where you need to define the feature columns, for example `feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]` which tells the classifier that it should expect 4 columns with real numbers in it.

Since skflow has been moved to tf.contrib.learn, you will probably find this helpful: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier
Anyway, `feature_columns` and `hidden_units` are obligatory in the function call.

I encountered some errors with `metrics.accuracy_score()`, so I replaced it with `classifier.evaluate()` and finally got it working.

See below for a full example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]
# made a change in the next line
classifier = skflow.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3)

classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target, steps=50)

score = classifier.evaluate(iris.data, iris.target, steps=1)["accuracy"]
print("Accuracy: {}".format(score))
```

A more extended example can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this may be: It's tensorflow version 0.8 and not the actual > 1. So just switch the version for this small example.

Comment: How to switch to another tf version ?